# Remove Add to Cart button on select products

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I would like to remove the "Add to Cart" button on specific products so that I can add a get a quote button instead. Is there a way I can insert a script within a product to pull the button?

Comment: you have to just create product level Yes/No Attribute, like show_add_button attribute and set it to your attribute set and set it value from product level, if product with yes value will show add to cart button and no will show quote button in phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case I was able to mark the products I wanted not for sale as out of stock. This in turn pulling the price and "add to cart" button. I was then able to add a get a quote button to the description which linked to the contact/quote page.